# Create extended anonymous class for Abstract class in TypeScript

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, abstract-class

I have `abstract` class which has few implemented `protected` methods and few `abstract` methods.
I am trying to write some tests for the `protected` methods.

Since these are not available even in the extended classes to outside world, I would like to create `anonymous Test class` which can extend and verify/mock my stuff.

```
export abstract class AbsClass implements AbsInterface {

    protected extract(filter: string) {
    //some implemented code to test
    }

    abstract someMethod();
}
```

I am not able to figure out how to create something like this `anonymously`

```
export class TestClass extends AbsClass {
   public testExtract(){
        //call super.extract and verify result
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. `TestClass` is not valid because it doesn't implement `abstract someMethod`.

Comment: @Aaron, I would mock that method or implement with some test code.

Comment: I still don't get it... are you asking how to extend an abstract class *without* implementing its abstract methods? What part of the code you've shown isn't working for you? How do you expect it to work?

Comment: @Aaron, Make it simple, that anonymous class `will implement` abstract methods. My question is how to create `anonymous class` in typescript which extends/implements `abstract class`

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "anonymous class". What part of the code you posted doesn't do what you want? What do you want it to do?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this before. It seems like the export/abstract keywords interfere with each other.  I've had to define the class and then export on a separate line to get around this.

Example:

```
abstract class BaseClass {}

export default BaseClass
```

Comment: `export abstract` should work. `export default abstract` doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Correct, I was assuming that the "anonymous" nature of the title indicated "default" but that may not be the case.

Comment: Ah, you might be right. I never would have guessed that. :) Maybe you could provide Reddy an example?

Comment: @ArcSine, an example would be really helpful for me and the future community :)

Answer (score 0):

There are some workarounds discussed in [this related issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30355).   See also:

- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36060
- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17293
- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35822

The short answer is that it's very difficult to represent anonymous classes that access private/protected members of their superclass right now.  If you're just trying to test parts of the superclass, does the implementing class really have to be anonymous?

(As an aside: I'm still pretty new at testing generally, but I've seen a lot of strongly worded advice about not explicitly testing private/protected methods.  Would it be preferable to test the public API methods that call the private/protected ones instead?)